# rank of partritioned matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Consider a matrix $X=[A, B, C]$ where $A,B$ and $C$ are matrices of full column rank. If we assume that $[A,B]$, $[B,C]$ and $[A,C]$ are of full column rank, can we say that $X$ is of full column rank? If so, how can I prove it?

Comment: try with 2-rows matrices and with $A,B,C$ composed each one of a single column...

Comment: If any of the three is full rank then so is #X$.